# How to use Gauss Package which displays as below?

Tags: math-mode, gauss

I want to use latex code to display gauss elimination as shown below.

[image: gauss elimination]

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gauss}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\smallvec}[2]{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \left.\begin{gmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 1
    \end{gmatrix}\right|
    \begin{gmatrix}
        \smallvec{0}{1} \\
        \smallvec{1}{0} \\
        \smallvec{2}{-1}
    \rowops
        \add[\cdot(-3)][+]{1}{2}
    \end{gmatrix}\sim\quad\left.\begin{gmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & \mathbf{\color{red} 0} & -2
    \end{gmatrix}\right|
    \begin{gmatrix}
        \smallvec{0}{1} \\
        \smallvec{1}{0} \\
        \smallvec{-1}{-1}
    \end{gmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments:

- You can't insert a vertical line inside a `gmatrix` environment, but you can put two two `gmatrix` next to each other with a vertical line in the middle. The row operations can then be added to the second `gmatrix` in the standard way.
- To have the vectors in the same size as the matrix entries, I use the environment `smallmatrix`. I defined the macro `\smallvec` to have a shorthand for that.
- If you are planning to use the combination of red + bold several times, you can define a shorthand macro for that, too:

  ```
  \newcommand{\mathemph}[1]{\mathbf{\color{red}#1}}
  ```