# gauss package set formatting (like the option for the array env)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices, gauss

until now, for me it was enough to make matrices that way:

```
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix}[cc|c]
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

with redifining the matrix env like this (see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2233/whats-the-best-way-make-an-augmented-coefficient-matrix)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{#1}
}
\makeatother
```

but now I need to use the `gauss` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gauss) but I still need the ability to set some kind of formatting string (like the `[cc|c]`). (to be specific, I need this vertical line to separate some columns from some other columns)

Can anyone help me to port the above described workaround to the `gauss` package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to typeset row operations on augmented matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146723/how-to-typeset-row-operations-on-augmented-matrix)

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't saw this post. I'd very much prefer the way having some kind of "format string" since this is much more convenient to use (and I think it shouldn't be too diffcult to implement since you'd only have to pass down this option to the array env on which the `gmatrix` is built on top of (I'm just not that firm in writing plain tex macros). But as a quick fix I think this will serve. Nevertheless I'd still really appreciate the (in my opinion) more clean version with a "format string".

Comment: I read in older answers that it isn't possible with `gmatrix`. However, you could recur to TikZ to emulate the `gauss` package features and still have a customizable matrix.

Comment: Where do you have read this (because from what I know this should be possible, in the worst case you'd have to make the "format string" a must have (not an optional parameter))

Comment: Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370323/how-to-use-gauss-package-which-displays-as-below. With a bit of patience you could write your own alternative to `gauss` and most of TeX.SX users (not me) are Tikz lovers, so you will be helped if you ask.

Comment: Hm, well let's see how much I later want that kind of format string ^^ but right now I think I'm too lazy for this. Thanks for researching ;) (you might want to write an answer ;)