# adopt gauss package (with tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, gauss

since I'm missing the ability to pass some kind of "format"-string to the `gmatrix` environment of the `gauss` package, and I learnt that this is not possible with redefining some environemnts used by the `gauss` package (see [gauss package set formatting (like the option for the array env)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543537/gauss-package-set-formatting-like-the-option-for-the-array-env)), I finally came to the point, when I decided to emulate some parts of the behaviour of the `gauss` package to be more flexible.

I just wanted to ask you if there is some way to attach tikz arrows onto elements of the `array` environment (and thus the pmatrix environment of the `amsmath` package) or if the only way to do something like this is by setting the whole array/matrix within tikz?

(If maybe someone has already done this (then I'd be glad if this one would share ;) ))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides environments `{NiceArray}`, `{NiceMatrix}`, `{pNiceMatrix}`, etc. similar to the environments of `array` and `amsmath` but with the creation of a PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells of the array.

It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}    
\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (1-3.east)  -- ++ (3mm,0) node [anchor = west]{\tiny $-3$} |- (2-3.east) ; 
\end{bNiceMatrix}$    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Excuse me very much for this disturb. Into your code there is `\tiny $-4$` in the picture I see `-3` :-). My regards.

Comment: @Sabastiano: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion, actually this looks pretty nice!

Comment: @F.Pantigny I like very much your package and I think that many users have appreciated it.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew you are the author ^^, (until now) I think it is a very nice package (especially for users like me, who like to insert tikz drawings into arrays/matrices). Thanks for writing ;)

Comment: Sadly this is not working when I try this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547932/nicematrix-codeafter-tikz-not-working