# nicematrix codeafter / tikz not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

consider my mwe:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        9 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    %
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz \draw (2-2) circle (2mm) ;
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

This is exactly the example of the manual/documentation, but sadly it is not working. (Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17         \CodeAfter
```

)
I already tried compiling with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex`

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

(in the end I want it in a normal math environment, I just took inline mode, since this is one step closer to the original example)

EDIT: When outsourcing the tikz part, it works (but especially for macro/environment writing this is a bit inconvenient)

Comment: The code works for me. Perhaps your packages are outdated.

Comment: If you go to the file where nicematrix is defined (here its `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty` whats the indicated Version (in line 21)? (mine is 3.6)

Comment: And my latex version (got with `pdflatex -v` is `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019`)

Comment: My log file: `Package: nicematrix 2020/05/27 v4.1`, `Package: tikz 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)`.  LaTex version: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)`

Comment: Well then maybe my version is too old :/

Comment: My guess is that it would be a package issue, not your LaTeX installation itself.

Comment: You can always check to see if the string `CodeAfter`appears in your version of `nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Yes it does (but as far as I see it, only with lowercase characters (but with `\codeafter` it won't work too)).

Comment: Hm, then I don't know what exactly the issue is, and  hope someone does or even maybe the author will read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\CodeAfter` in version 3.6 of `nicematrix`. It has been introduced in version 3.15.

However, this keyword `\CodeAfter` is only an alternative syntax to specify what is called the `code-after` in the documentation of `nicematrix`. You can acheive your goal by using the key `code-after` (available since version 2.1).

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    $\begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
        9 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    %
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[code-after = \tikz \draw (2-2) circle (2mm) ;]
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

If you decide to update `nicematrix` to the most recent version (4.1), you will have to update also your whole TeX installation because that version uses features in very recent versions of `expl3` (which is now a part of the LaTeX kernel).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I'll have to wait for arch linux to update their latex package.

Comment: Yes, already tried to only update your package (didn't work as you said). Now I'm trying to collect my tikz code in a pgf key to insert it later on (for environment writing) but up to now it doesn't work (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547943/latex-environment-writing-generate-tikz-code-but-insert-it-later-maybe-with-ti).