# latex nicematrix -- access generated nodes from tikz

Tags: nicematrix

Is it normal that I cannot access the by `nicematrix` generated Tikz nodes within the same `align` environment?

Example:

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=myMatrix]
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw (myMatrix-1-1) -- (myMatrix-1-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
```

won't work, but

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=myMatrix]
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (myMatrix-1-1) -- (myMatrix-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

works.

This is a bit inconvenient when one wants to stay in the same `align` environment after the `pNiceMatrix` (otherwise there will be free space between the matrix and the next line in the same environment and writing in the same line as the matrix is not possible (at least it's difficult when writing macros).

Is there a way to "fix" this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment `{align}` of `amsmath` compiles its contents twice. The aim of the first compilation is to measure the width of the content of the environment.

The package `nicematrix` does not create the PGF/Tikz nodes during that first compilation.

However, you can write a command which will execute its argument only during the second compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \WhenNotMeasuring { } { \legacy_if:nF {measuring@} }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=myMatrix]
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
    \WhenNotMeasuring
      {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw (myMatrix-1-1) -- (myMatrix-1-2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good (not tested yet) but will there by any disadvantages by using `legacy` (and could you explain what the `\legacy_if:nF {measuring@}` does?)

Comment: What a tex-nical trick!

Comment: @atticus `amsmath` uses boolean `\ifmeasuring@` to test if it is in "measure" typeset phase or "production" phase (see [`amsmath` implementation notes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf), sec. 17.2). `\legacy_if:nF{<latex2e boolean>}{<if false>}` is the latex3 style if-then-else function (see [`texdoc interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), Part XXXIV).

Comment: Yes. The word `legacy` means that this is a latex3 conditional structure using an TeX boolean in the old style. There is no problem in using it.

Comment: Oh, ok there is so much I don't know. When will the if end? With the end of the outer environment (in that case `align`) like when using something like `\centering`?

Comment: @atticus The constructed command `\WhenNotMeasuring` takes one argument, and executes it only if `\ifmeasuring@` is false, aka in the amsmath "production" phase. To sum up, in `align*`'s "measure" phase (first typeset), the `pNiceMatrix` is constructed and tikz code is omit, and in "production" phase (second typeset), `pNiceMatrix` is constructed again with cell nodes drawn and the following tikz code relying those cell nodes is executed.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand (completely). Then this looks really promising. Thanks a lot. I'll try

Comment: Ok, I have two Questions left 1) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548012/latex-tikz-foreach-loops-strange (second is that up to now I cannot set the pgfkey inside the `nicematrix` but only within the `tikzpicture` but this will be part of another question for which I'll have to wait because of the  stackexchange cooldown)

Answer (score 4):

`align*` environment typesets its contents twice, and I believe this causes your problem.

Recent version of `nicematrix` package provides a command `\CodeAfter` which is helpful in your case. Note that you can even omit the `[name=myMatrix]` part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 
        \CodeAfter
        \tikz \draw (1-1) -- (1-2);
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Sadly the archLinux latex package is too old for that (don't know when the update will be) and somehow I don't want to install the whole package from somewhere else :/ (but yes, with `CodeAfter` in the end of the matrix environment would solve my problem. (the `codeAfter` option does not work, since I want to write my own environment which has to collect the things, I want to draw at first, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1384141?noredirect=1 for a description of my goal)

Comment: @atticus Ah I noticed your previous question [adopt gauss package (with tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547751) and have looked into `gauss` implementation for a while. Maybe we can wrap tikz commands to emulate `gauss` commands. I will re-read your previous questions to make sure I don't mis-understand your requirement.

Comment: What would be your idea to do so? Until now I think to hav found a very elegant solution with the use of `nicemartrix` since that way one can easily attach arrows onto elements of the matrix.

Comment: @atticus If we want to emulate the `gauss` commands then `nicematrix` is the most easy approach. I also wonder if `gauss` is patchable to support tabular preamble like `cc|c`. Since `gauss` uses align primitives, which I am not familiar with, to construct the matrix, I have not found the way to patch `gauss`.

Comment: Yes, I tried to read the `gauss` code too (but I'm not that experienced) but didn't found something.