# tikz / nicematrix boundaries (+ tikz coordinates explanation in the comments)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nicematrix

When adding a `tikzpicture` to a `NiceMatrix` which draws lines outside the matrix, the bounding box' of the matrix is not increased. Is there a way to fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}\rightarrow
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw (mymatrix-1-5) -- ++(5em,0) |- (mymatrix-2-5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Overlapping]

I guess the problem is with the `overlay` option in `tikzpicture`, but when removing it, the drawing isn't placed **on** the matrix, but only below.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, `overlay` means that the bounding box gets not increased, but is essential for adding annotations to nodes that have been created before. So, in short, you will to have to devise a different strategy if you want to make the annotation part of the matrix. However, is seems to me that you do not even want to do that, rather you seem to want to shift the second matrix far enough to the right. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes adding the space would be already enough, I just thought, the increase of the bounding box would be the (only) way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, `overlay` means that the bounding box gets not increased, but is essential for adding annotations to nodes that have been created before. However, one can measure how much the annotation overshoots the original matrix, and add the corresponding horizontal space.

You seem to be using an older version of `nicematrix`. Here is something that adds the required horizontal space after the first matrix. Analogous methods can be used for the newer versions, too. Since this is only a proof of principle I did not make an effort in avoiding global macros, the more so since this will become much easier with the next version of pgf.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548004
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \WhenNotMeasuring { } { \legacy_if:nF {measuring@} }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=mymatrix]
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}\tikzmark{R1}
        \WhenNotMeasuring
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          \begin{scope}[local bounding box=annot]   
           \draw (mymatrix-1-5) -- ++(5em,0) |- (mymatrix-2-5);
          \end{scope}
          \path let \p1=($(pic cs:R1)-(annot.west)$),
          \p2=($(annot.east)-(annot.west)$)
           in \pgfextra{\xdef\myshift{\the\dimexpr\x2-\x1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{\myshift}}
        \rightarrow
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}[name=myothermatrix]
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}\tikzmark{R2}
        \WhenNotMeasuring
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          \begin{scope}[local bounding box=annot]   
           \draw (myothermatrix-1-5) -- ++(5em,0) |- (myothermatrix-2-5)
           node[pos=0.25,right]{$a$};
          \end{scope}
          \path let \p1=($(pic cs:R2)-(annot.west)$),
          \p2=($(annot.east)-(annot.west)$)
           in \pgfextra{\xdef\myshift{\the\dimexpr\x2-\x1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hspace{\myshift}}
        \rightarrow
        \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
        \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow I cannot find `tikzmark` in the tikz/pgf documentation, may there be a typo?
And how do you convert the coordinates you get from tikz to a length to insert into `hspace`? (up do now, I didn't found a source that explains, what `\dimexpr` does)

Comment: @atticus `tikzmark` is a library by Andrew Stacey, which is not part of the pgf bundle. It is a very useful library. `\dimexpr` is part of etex, it allows you to add lengths (for instance).

Comment: Ok, found the corresponding docs, thanks. But I still wonder why after subtracting two coordinates results in a length.

Comment: @atticus The components of the coordinates, `\x1` and `\x2` in these examples, *are* lengths (or, more precisely, macros that evaluate to something of the form `<x>pt`, where `x` is a real number). All that is done is to subtract the distance of the right end of the matrix to  `(myothermatrix-1-5)` from the width of the annotation.

Comment: Oh, and I always thought `annot.east` would return the `tikz` coordinates of that point.

Comment: @atticus Yes, that is correct. It does not contradict anything I said above.

Comment: Well now you confuse me, for me the `tikz` coordinates always were completely independent of any outer dimensions, now you say the `tikz`coordinates are are the `pt`s of the outer LaTeX page (or do I understand you wrong?) (this becomes a bit off topic now, but I'd really like to settle this)

Comment: @atticus The Ti*k*Z coordinates are defined relative to some origin. However, since we are only interested in differences, the location of the origin does not matter. I never said that the Ti*k*Z coordinates are relative to the origin of the page (but of course you may arrange for that). I guess the issue here is mainly wording. Now there are three terms, dimensions, lengths and coordinates, which get mixed up.

Comment: Yes indeed different origins are no problem (regarding differences) but the scaling has to fit, so one unit in `tikz` coordinates is then `1pt` in LaTeX right?

Comment: @atticus No. One unit is whatever you define it to be, by default it is `1cm`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606. But what matters here is that we extract the distance in pt (and do not use any scale factors). These distances have the same interpretation in the ambient LaTeX code.

Comment: So `$(pic cs:R2)-(annot.west)$` then returns the distance in pt right?

Comment: @atticus Not quite. It is the difference of two coordinates. So if you have `\p1=($(pic cs:R2)-(annot.west)$)`, then `\x1` will be the x component of that difference, and `\y1` its y component, each of them in `pt`. If you use `\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}`, `\n1` will contain the distance, also in `pt`.

Comment: "each of them in `pt`" that was my point. Now finally I think, I've got it. Thanks for your kindness. (if you have a suggestion how to rename the post so that it fits the topic of our discussion in the comments, just let me know ;) )